# How can I adapt my code to take the desired screenshot, cropping both top and bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, screenshot

I have the following `Kotlin` code which takes a screenshot of the area shown:

```
fun screenShot() {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(wholeScreen.width,wholeScreen.height-gameDimensions.bottomNavigationViewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, gameDimensions.verticalInc.toInt(), bitmap.width, (bitmap.height - gameDimensions.verticalInc).toInt())
    val canvas = Canvas(croppedBitmap)
    wholeScreen.draw(canvas)
    val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    croppedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out)
    val screenShot = ColourBoardScreenShot(BitmapDrawable(theUi.resources, croppedBitmap))
    bundle.putParcelable ("screenshot", screenShot)
}
```

Original screen:

[image]

Current Screenshot:

[image]

Desired Screenshot:

[image]

It's somewhat embarrassing but I cannot figure out how to take the screenshot in blue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the canvas position from 0,0 to the new position by  Add

`canvas.translate(0, -gameDimensions.verticalInc.toInt())` before wholeScreen.draw(canvas)

Comment: Thanks but no, the verticalInc is not zero. The cropping works but it crops the bottom and I want it to crop the top.

Comment: Try `  canvas.translate(0, gameDimensions.verticalInc.toInt()) ` before  `wholeScreen.draw(canvas)`

Comment: `canvas.translate(0.toFloat(), -gameDimensions.verticalInc)` did the trick.  Edit your answer accordingly and I'll mark it as correct.  All the best